# Use generic for deserializing with gson

Tags: android, json, generics, serialization, gson

I have a very specific question for deserializing a generic with gson.
I'm using a combination of square otto and tape to queue all my events I use for requests. 
Therefore I use a generic load data event with an enum to know which request to send:

```
public class GenericLoadDataEvent<T> {
    private LoadDataEnum mDataEnum;
    T mRequestData;

    public GenericLoadDataEvent(LoadDataEnum dataEnum, T requestData) {
        mDataEnum = dataEnum;
        this.mRequestData = requestData;
    }

    {...}
}
```

and the data holding class to serialize:

```
public class ServerTask implements Task<ServerTask.ServerTaskCallback>  {
   public static final String TAG = ServerTask.class.getSimpleName();

   private LoadDataEnum mDataEnum;
   private GenericLoadDataEvent mGenericLoadDataEvent;

   public ServerTask(GenericLoadDataEvent event) {
       mGenericLoadDataEvent = event;
       mDataEnum = event.getDataEnum();
   }

   {...}
```

}

Serializing to tape works quite fine but when I deserialize the tape entry with gson I'm always getting a com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap instead of the Object in the GenericLoadDataEvent, because Gson don't know which class to use for the T requestData Object.

I'm using a GsonConverter for serializing and deserializing, where T is ServerTask in this case:

```
public class GsonConverter<T> implements FileObjectQueue.Converter<T> {

private final Gson gson;
private final Class<T> type;

public GsonConverter(Gson gson, Class<T> type) {
    this.gson = gson;
    this.type = type;
}


/**
 * Converts bytes to an object.
 *
 * @param bytes
 */
@Override
public T from(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
    return gson.fromJson(reader, type);
}
```

My question is now - how can i tell gson which class the T mRequestData from the GenericLoadDataEvent should be?

I tried something like:

```
public class ServerTask<T> implements Task<ServerTask.ServerTaskCallback> {
public static final String TAG = ServerTask.class.getSimpleName();

private LoadDataEnum mDataEnum;
private GenericLoadDataEvent<T> mGenericLoadDataEvent;

public ServerTask(GenericLoadDataEvent event) {
    mGenericLoadDataEvent = event;
    mDataEnum = event.getDataEnum();
}
```

But that's not working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial will help. They add a type name for generics.
http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-google-json-serializing-classes-with-generic-type.jsp